# OpenCV addweighted does not work because of inRange cmd before

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

In a OpenCV project I'm trying to blend to images with `addweighted`.

In the beginning of the section I make sure, all the `Mat`-objects have the same settings

```
HSVgreen = calibHSV;
HSVblue = calibHSV;
HSVyellow = calibHSV;
HSVred = calibHSV;
HSVall = calibHSV;
```

After this, I'm using an `inRange` operation:

```
inRange(calibHSV, Scalar(H_MIN, S_MIN, V_MIN), Scalar(H_MAX, S_MAX, V_MAX), HSVred);
```

Right after the `inRange` there is the `addWeighted` command which brings me the *"Size of input arguments does not match"* exception.

```
addWeighted(HSVgreen,ALPHA_VAL,HSVred,ALPHA_VAL,0.0,HSVall);
```

After inspecting the args for a while I found out that the `HSVred Mat` gets changed during a `inRange` operation just befor the `addWeighted` cmd.

In the section "step" of the `HSVred`-Object ,the argument "p" gets changed from 1200 to 400, so that a changes happens to the array"`buf`".
What does this change mean? What do I need to do, so I still can execute this `addWeighted` command?

Comment: Hey guys. Just right now I got the problem...
the inRange operation gives me a 1-channel mat back. the other ones are 3 channel ones... this cannot workout of course.

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to your question title. If one of the answers helped you to solve the problem, [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) by clicking the check mark in the left margin. If none of the answers were useful and you figured out a solution of your own, post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just check the doc, here is the inRange function:

[image: OpenCV doc: inRange()]

So your input array is a three channels picture, and the output array will be a one channel picture, that is why 1200 has been changed to 400. (1200/3)